# Shoutcast aac+ player app android like tunein

Tags: android, flash, builder

Im looking for an example or a guide to how create an app like tunein to have my own list of stations then if i make click in one shows me a player to play de stream i basically use aac+ also have wowza server rtmp links etc but i need some hide maybe or documentation that i can follow to start.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it connecting to the RTMP address using NetConnection and then start playing the stream. I've never done it with AAC+ but i think (maybe i'm wrong) it's the same thing as with an mp3 stream.

Maybe you could start by reading this http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217-Quick-Start-Guide or more specific -> Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP - Adobe Flash Player) http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217#flashRTMP

Also, when i started to (work?) experiment with RTMP, i found very useful articles here http://www.flashrealtime.com/?s=rtmp maybe this should be your starting point.